# Set all array values to 0 with Lambda/linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is it possible to set all int array values to 0 with Lambda/Linq?

```
public int[] Reset()
{
    int[] M = new int[MIlg]; \\MIlg - length of array
    for (int i = 0; i < M.Length; i++)
    {
        M[i] = 0;
    }
    return M;
}
```

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not modifying.

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly advise you to use more meaningful names - `MIlg` is a very obscure name, IMO.

Comment: In c#, new array of int will always create continuous block of int with 0 value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is inherently about querying, not modifying. But there's already a method that does this - [`Array.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
```

That's assuming you want to clear an existing array, of course. Your current method doesn't make much sense, as a new array already *starts* with every element set to the default, so you can just use `new int[length]`. I'd expect a method called `Reset` to affect an *existing* array.